# Why doesn't the cordova-plugin-background-mode plugin work on android?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to send the geolocation by ajax in intervals of 30 seconds in the background, since this application is being used to know the "real time" location of the deliverers at all times. The problem is that when you enable the plugin in the android version when generating the apk and installing it on the cell phone it doesn't work, even when you put the application in the background and put it back in the foreground it restarts completely.
These are the versions that I am using for the development of the application:

- Cordova 10
- Nodejs 14.16
- JQuery 3.5

Structure:

- js

  - login.js
  - home.js
- index.html  -- this is the login page where the login.js file is located
- home.html -- this is the home page where the home.js file is located

***login.js***

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
});
```

***home.js***

```
let isSending = false;
let intervalId = null;
let email = window.localStorage.getItem("user_email");
let token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
let path = window.localStorage.getItem("api_url");

let onMapSuccess = function (position) {
    let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    if (!isSending) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: path + "/geoTransportista/" + email + "/" + latitude + "/" + longitude,
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
                "Content-type": "application/json",
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                isSending = true;
            }
        }).done((res) => {
            if (res.state == "successful") console.log("ENVIO EXITOSO");
        }).fail((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        }).always(() => {
            isSending = false;
        });
    }
};

let onMapError = function (error) {
    isSending = false;
}

let getLocation = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onMapSuccess, onMapError, {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
    });
    return getLocation;
}
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function (e) {
  intervalId = setInterval(getLocation(), 30000);
  cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.on('activate', function (e) {
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();
        if (intervalId) clearInterval(intervalId);
        intervalId = setInterval(getLocation(), 30000); 
  });
  cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.on('deactivate', function (e) {
        if (intervalId) clearInterval(intervalId);
        intervalId = setInterval(getLocation(), 30000); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@justin is wrong it works on Cordova 10+ but it does not support GPS however you can recall GPS function when you resume to app. I'm on Cordova 11.0.0 and its working fine. Also you can take a look a cordova-plugin-advanced-background-mode

Answer (score 0):

cordova-plugin-background-mode does not work on Cordova 10. You can try downgrade to Cordova 9. The [repo](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) seems inactive for a while now, not sure if the author will ever fix it.